# How to mock "io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Network closed for unknown reason" when doing grpc call?

Tags: grpc

I'm implementing a retry logic for my grpc call, when it saw StatusRuntimeException it will do retry several times.
My question is how can I mock the call will throw StatusRuntimeException?

My thought is to set the alive time and alive timeout really small, like 5mills, is that works? Or is there any other good way to do that

```
NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress()
            .keepAliveTime(5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .keepAliveTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .keepAliveWithoutCalls(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

grpc-java has retry feature out-of-box, you might try:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/retrying

[gRPC A8](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/A8-client-side-keepalive.md) suggests never set keepalive time within 1min, you would see GOAWAY from server if so.

> Suggests for clients to avoid configuring their keepalive much below one minute (see Server Enforcement section for additional details)

Actually, if you simply no not start a server, you see `StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception`